# Passing value from select control to function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have create a select control that has a default option and a number of different options which should allow me to style a heading in a number of different ways.

I can see my select changing value(note the console.log) so I know it's working fine.

```
const MySelectControl = withState( {
   size: 'display-2',
} )( ( { size, setState } ) => (
   <SelectControl
   label="Size"
   value={ size }
   options={ [
       { label: 'Display 1', value: 'display-1' },
       { label: 'Display 2', value: 'display-2' },
       { label: 'Display 3', value: 'display-3' },
       { label: 'Display 4', value: 'display-4' },
   ] }
   onChange={ ( size ) => { setState( { size }, console.log(size + ' from func')  ) } }
   />
) );

// Block Options
const withInspectorControls =  createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {


   return (props) => {
       return (
           <Fragment>
           <BlockEdit { ...props } />
           <InspectorControls>
           <PanelBody
           title="Display Block Settings"
           initialOpen={ true }
           >

           <MySelectControl />

           </PanelBody>
           </InspectorControls>
           </Fragment>
       );
   };
}, "withInspectorControl" );

wp.hooks.addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'display-heading/with-inspector-controls', withInspectorControls );


function handleSize(){
   return MySelectControl.value;
}


const sizeH = handleSize();
```

I have created a function that handles the value however when I try to return the value in the  function handlesize 'return MySelectControl.value', my result is undefined rather than display-2 or any other option.

I can't seem to be able to get the value what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing this: -

1. Create a select control in the edit function.

```
{

  <SelectControl
      label="Size"
      value={ size }
      options={ [
          { label: 'Display 1', value: 'display-1' },
          { label: 'Display 2', value: 'display-2' },
          { label: 'Display 3', value: 'display-3' },
          { label: 'Display 4', value: 'display-4' },
      ] }
   onChange={ ( size ) => props.setAttributes( { size: size } ) }
      />

}
```

2. Create an attribute (size)
3. Change the select control to change the size attribute
4. Pass the props to the save function props.attributes.size

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleSize(){
   return MySelectControl.value;
}
```

Do you not want MySelectControl.size rather than value? Or likely something like (I'm not sure which) MySelectControl.props.size or MySelectControl.props.attributes.size.

It might be helpful to console.log(MySelectControl)

Comment: Kinda, display-2 should be the default size however it should pass back any option from the control and MySelectControl.props.size, MySelectControl.props.attributes.size both return undefined